# Interpretation of a low BIC value but variables insignificant in Mixed Model

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, spss, bic

From the output of two mixed models that I have, Model A has a BIC value of 400 with 8 variables, with only 3 of them significant at 0.05 level.

On the other hand, model B has a BIC value of 700 but with 4 variables only, and all the variables are significant at the 0.05 level.

Assuming the difference between BIC values is statistically significant(which means both models are quite different), which model should I select: the simpler model with all variables significant or the more complicated model with lower BIC value and high number of insignificant variables?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Check whether the models is fitted on the same data. If you run both models separately, and if there are missings on some of the variables, and if you handle missings by list-wise deletion, it is possible that the model with 4 variables includes more cases and by this produces a higher BIC.

If both models are based on the same data, the decision is based on the purpose of your model. Normally you would choose the model with the lower BIC, regardless the number of sign. variables. If your model is a regression like model, multicollinearity can inflate standard errors. The latter causes that predictors are not sign. ; However, the overall model may still be very good in terms of prediction and explained variance.

If prediction is most important to you, you can estimate both models on half the data, and test the prediction capabilities on the other half of the data.

Furthermore, it would be great to get more details of the model you are running. ;)